# Android: how to run a complex website on local http server? (with nanohttpd or equivalent)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, server, nanohttpd

I want my Android app to execute a complex website on a local http server directly on the phone.

For that, I implemented [nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd). With this library, I can run locally on my phone on a http server some simple html code like this:

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
        if (parms.get("username") == null) {
            msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
        } else {
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
        }
        return newFixedLengthResponse( msg + "</body></html>\n" );
    }
```

Similar code can be see in the demo app [here](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/org/nanohttpd/samples/http/DebugServer.java).

But what I want is to run a full complex website with an index.html file and many other files (namely javascript files). To be more specific, I want to run a WebGL website on a local server on my Android phone.

So, I have all the files of my website in the 'assets' folder of my apk. When the app launches, I copy all the files to the internal storage of the Android phone (to file:///storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.example.mysuperapp/files )

Thus, index.html is located in /files.

How can I do if I want that http://192.168.0.26:8080/index.html runs smoothly the website located at file:///storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.example.mysuperapp/files/index.html ? (meaning that all the javascript files, imports, etc... should work properly)

If nanohttpd is not designed for that, is there any other tool to do that?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Presumably, `serve()` would look at the request path, map it to a file, and serve the contents of the file. Note that from a security standpoint, at minimum your server will be visible to all apps on the device, and possibly broader than that. FWIW, [this free older edition of one of my books](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.7-CC.pdf) has a chapter on embedding a Web server in an Android app, though I used [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync).